# Wordpress. "the_post()" loop doesn't iterate on all posts

Tags: wordpress

Loop on my front page not showing results.

```
<?php define('WP_USE_THEMES', false); get_header(); ?>
<div class="site-row clear">
    <div class="center">
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
        <div class="showcase">
            <?php
                if ( have_posts() ) :
                    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                        echo '1';
                    endwhile;
                endif;
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

It's show '1', but i have lot posts. People, tell me please what i do wrong?

UPD.
This code is in front-page.php . On local server all posts showing, but on hosting didn't show. Instead Echo '1' i use the_content(). echo '1' just for debugging.

Comment: can you paste entire code of loop please?

Comment: all post are published or pending, draft

Comment: all post are published

Comment: Please give us a little more context, for instance if you want a section within for instance "homepage" and do the code above all it will show is the main page. You would need to add more argument to the query in order to pull more information. But anyways more context would be appreciated.

Comment: I have a wordpress theme. it consist of index.php, style.css, front-page.php, page.php, single.php, sidebar.php, header.php, footer.php, index.php. Index.php is empty. All showing normal, but posts are missing.

Comment: why in loop  echo '1'; you have to put code like the_title() and the_content(); check codex for display content inside loop..https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop_in_Action

Comment: thank you. But i read this article many times already((( Echo '1' it's just for debugging.

Comment: Thank to all!!!Problem solved. In Wordpress settings in Reding sections, on main page display: i choose nothing and all posts are shows.